# SQL Server Sum Columns From Two Tables With Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

**Sales**:

```
 SaleID | DayNumber | Quantity | ProductID
    1   | 1         | 10       | 1
    2   | 1         | 150      | 4
    3   | 1         | 70       | 6
    4   | 2         | 30       | 2
    5   | 2         | 40       | 3
    6   | 2         | 45       | 5
    7   | 2         | 15       | 8
```

and **Products**:

```
ProductID | Price
1         | 12
2         | 52
3         | 643
4         | 42
5         | 75
6         | 53
7         | 2
8         | 7
```

So I wanna do get some results, but I have no idea how can I do them. I want to calculate for example the sum of the sold products for days 2,3 and 4. And also the average earnings for each day.

Comment: Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: I tried some stuff, but nothing so far, I expect some thing like that:
Day | Total              | Average
 1     | 591 (for ex.)  | 45
 2     | 825               | 36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need this simple sum with join query

```
create table #sales
(id int not null identity(1,1),
 DayNUmber int,
 Quantity int,
 ProductID int)

 create table #Products(
 id int not null identity(1,1),
 Price money
 )
insert #sales
values
(1,10,1),
(1,150,4),
(1,70,6),
(2,30,2),
(2,40,3),
(2,45,5),
(2,5,8);

insert #Products
values
(12),
(52),
(643),
(42),
(75),
(53),
(2),
(5);



select 
sum(s.Quantity*p.Price) as [sum],
s.DayNumber from #sales s inner join #Products p
on s.ProductID=p.id  where s.DayNumber in (2,3)
group by s.DayNUmber
```

Answer (score 0):

Join on common ID. 
Take sum of Quantity * Price. 
Group by Day and filter as needed.

```
SELECT
SUM(Quantity*Price)
,DayNumber
FROM Sales s
INNER JOIN PRODUCT p ON p.ProductID = s.ProductID
WHERE DayNumber IN(2,3,4)
GROUP BY DayNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

To make this work you need to [JOIN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) the two tables in your query. You can then use [SUM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql) to calculate the sum of the sold products and earnings. To filter for days 2, 3, and 4 you can use [IN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql) in your [WHERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql) clause.

```
SELECT S.DayNumber, SUM(S.Quantity) AS 'Products Sold', SUM(S.Quantity * P.Price) AS 'Total Earnings'
FROM Sales AS S JOIN Products AS P ON S.ProductID = P.ProductID
WHERE S.DayNumber IN (2, 3, 4)
GROUP BY S.DayNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

You need AVG per day and Total Sale per day. Filter as per the days required

```
SELECT SUM(p.Price * s.Quantity) TotalsalePerday, AVG(p.Price * s.Quantity) AvgsalePerday ,s.DayNumber from SO_Products p
    INNER JOIN SO_Sales s ON p.ProductID = s.ProductID
    GROUP BY DayNumber
    ORDER BY DayNumber
```

/*------------------------
OUTPUT
------------------------*/

```
TotalsalePerday AvgsalePerday DayNumber
--------------- ------------- -----------
10130           3376          1
30760           7690          2

(2 row(s) affected)
```